# Jquery.Get ashx page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

JS method

```
$.post('http://localhost:21067/HandlerServices/Product/ProductHandler.ashx', 'action=productlist', function (data) { console.log(data); console.log('hi') });
```

This ashx code is working but i recive nothing in response

This is ashx.cs code

```
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.QueryString["action"]))
  {
    string action = context.Request.QueryString["action"];

    switch (action.ToLower())
    {
      case "productlist":

        context.Response.Write("ersoy");
        break;
    }
  }
```

[image: get response]

I have query 1.9.0 version. In response tag not appeare anything.
Before i used it many times but now i cant understand where is the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are violating the [`same origin policy restriction`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) that's built in browsers. Your ASP.NET MVC application containing this javascript file is hosted on `http://localhost:2197` but you are attempting to perform an AJAX request to `http://localhost:21067` which cannot work.

There are some workarounds such as using [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (works only with GET requests) or [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (works only in modern browsers that support it). If for some reason you cannot use some of those techniques you could have a server side controller action inside your ASP.NET MVC application which will perform the actual call to the remote domain and act as a bridge between the 2. Then from your client script you will send the AJAX request to your own domain.